# How to read the following probability mass function?

Tags: probability

This question is based on the following post ["How to read uniform_int_distribution's probability mass function?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051097/how-to-read-uniform-int-distributions-probability-mass-function).

**uniform_int_distribution** is a C++ class template that generates uniformly distributed integer random values, which have the following probability mass function:

$$P(i | a, b) = \frac{1}{b - a + 1}$$

The answer given in the earlier post (for uniform_int_distribution) was as follows:

> This means "P (the chance) of outcome i, depending on parameters a and b, is (1/b-a+1) ...".

**binomial_distribution** is another C++ class template that generates random values which have the following probability mass function:

$$P(i|t, p) = \bigg(_i^t p^i(1 - p)^{t - i} \bigg), 0 \le p \le 1 \;and\; 0 \le t $$

Based on the answer given in the earlier post, I'm having a go at reading this function:

> "**P** (the probability) of outcome **i** (dependent on parameters **t** and **p**) is given by $p^i(1 - p)^{t - i}$, where **i** is varied from **0** (the lower limit for **t**) and **t**.

Is this correct (as per the earlier answer)?

Comment: The two statements do not contradict eachothere (if that's what you mean). In both statements the same sort of notation is practicized. $P(i\mid *,*)=\dots$ where the * corresponds with parameters (in both case two, but that could be different) and on RHS an expression that gives in the first case a PMF and in the second  case also a PMF. In both cases $i$ is the variable.

Comment: In the second case, the probability) of outcome $i$ is ${t\choose i}p^i(1 - p)^{t - i}$, not $p^i(1 - p)^{t - i}$. Since you have been given the name of the relevant distributions, checking their WP pages might help.

Comment: My query was essentially about how to read the $(_i^t)$ part. Did I get that part right? I read it as "varying i from 0 to t".